# https handshake fails from JavaScript client to Node.js/socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, socket.io, handshake

I'm able to handshake from a JavaScript client (NOT browser or Node.js based) to a Node.js server that uses socket.io using http but not https. For https, the server code includes

```
var app = express();
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("server.cert")
};
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var socketio = require("socket.io");
var io = socketio.listen(server);
server.listen(443);
```

and the client code includes

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://localhost:443/socket.io/1/");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState !== 4){
    return;
  }
  callback({status: xhr.status,
            header: xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(),
            body: xhr.responseText
    });
  };
xhr.send();
```

The client is run after the server has started but the handshake fails with the values

```
readyState: 4
status: 0
header: 
body:
```

Does the client need to include some security info or do something else for the handshake to work with https and get a session ID?

Comment: Establishing a connection through an `XMLHttpRequest` is not the recommended way of connecting to socketio. What language is your client in?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript but plan to deploy to mobile platforms. I'm just using XmlHttpRequest for the handshake.

Comment: I don't think it can be used to handshake like that. You might need to use some kind of library for this.

Comment: Try getting `https://localhost:[port]/socket.io/socket.io.js` instead

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work.

Comment: doing a `GET` at that location only gets the client side socket file. You still have to find some way to load it up into whatever equates to a DOM and make it accessible for use by javascript. If it were html, you could just do `<script src=...`